# R Methodology: Control and I/O between laptop R and large computational servers

Tags: r

This is a general methodology question regarding R as means to:

- set up and start jobs on remote computational platforms for various intensive modeling tasks,
- then acquire data from these remote computational servers, and
- then do analysis.

R is certainly up to the task for this and I believe this is an issue that many others have contemplated and performed, so I hope to learn from prior experiences.

I'm currently using R together with the R system command to drive the `Putty` programs `pscp` and `Plink` to transfer a batch file, invoke a process, wait till it's done and then copy the results back for processing.

This I admit is crude, but it works surprisingly well.

Are there better ways?  The data files coming back can be large.

I would like to determine the next step in an incremental progression without going too crazy.  It needs to be be simple.

Comment: Rserve might be what you want if the server is running R too but Rserve doesn't support propper callbacks by default but wrapping one is trivial.

Comment: +1, interesting question, I also thought of a distributed computations in R :-) Bob, please report your final solution here as an answer.

Comment: Thank you both.  I will look into Rserve and will let you know of my results.  Bob

Comment: I have the beginnings of some code like this that you might be interested in -- google & e-mail me if you want me to send you stuff

Answer (score 0):

There is a (fun) 8 min video of client/server interaction on the [data.table homepage](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/) that may or may not be of interest. But, have you looked at everthing on the [HPC Task View](http://www.stats.bris.ac.uk/R/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) already? That doesn't seem to mention Rserve, though, so look at that too as Hansi suggested.